# Latex Tikz - align figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, plot

I would like to align two figures in such a way that top right corner of small figure will be on top right corner on the big figure. How to do it? I would also like that when scaling a large figure a small figure would automatically change positions to remain in the upper right corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
-9.424778,-0.000000
-9.414778,-0.010000
-9.404778,-0.019999
-9.394778,-0.029996
-9.384778,-0.039989
-9.374778,-0.049979
-9.364778,-0.059964
-9.354778,-0.069943
-9.344778,-0.079915
-9.334778,-0.089879
-9.324778,-0.099833
-9.314778,-0.109778
-9.304778,-0.119712
-9.294778,-0.129634
-9.284778,-0.139543
-9.274778,-0.149438
-9.264778,-0.159318
-9.254778,-0.169182
-9.244778,-0.179030
-9.234778,-0.188859
-9.224778,-0.198669
-9.214778,-0.208460
-9.204778,-0.218230
-9.194778,-0.227978
-9.184778,-0.237703
-9.174778,-0.247404
-9.164778,-0.257081
-9.154778,-0.266731
-9.144778,-0.276356
-9.134778,-0.285952
-9.124778,-0.295520
-9.114778,-0.305059
-9.104778,-0.314567
-9.094778,-0.324043
-9.084778,-0.333487
-9.074778,-0.342898
-9.064778,-0.352274
-9.054778,-0.361615
-9.044778,-0.370920
-9.034778,-0.380188
-9.024778,-0.389418
-9.014778,-0.398609
-9.004778,-0.407760
-8.994778,-0.416871
-8.984778,-0.425939
-8.974778,-0.434966
-8.964778,-0.443948
-8.954778,-0.452886
-8.944778,-0.461779
-8.934778,-0.470626
-8.924778,-0.479426
-8.914778,-0.488177
-8.904778,-0.496880
-8.894778,-0.505533
-8.884778,-0.514136
-8.874778,-0.522687
-8.864778,-0.531186
-8.854778,-0.539632
-8.844778,-0.548024
-8.834778,-0.556361
-8.824778,-0.564642
-8.814778,-0.572867
-8.804778,-0.581035
-8.794778,-0.589145
-8.784778,-0.597195
-8.774778,-0.605186
-8.764778,-0.613117
-8.754778,-0.620986
-8.744778,-0.628793
-8.734778,-0.636537
-8.724778,-0.644218
-8.714778,-0.651834
-8.704778,-0.659385
-8.694778,-0.666870
-8.684778,-0.674288
-8.674778,-0.681639
-8.664778,-0.688921
-8.654778,-0.696135
-8.644778,-0.703279
-8.634778,-0.710353
-8.624778,-0.717356
-8.614778,-0.724287
-8.604778,-0.731146
-8.594778,-0.737931
-8.584778,-0.744643
-8.574778,-0.751280
-8.564778,-0.757843
-8.554778,-0.764329
-8.544778,-0.770739
-8.534778,-0.777072
-8.524778,-0.783327
-8.514778,-0.789504
-8.504778,-0.795602
-8.494778,-0.801620
-8.484778,-0.807558
-8.474778,-0.813416
-8.464778,-0.819192
-8.454778,-0.824886
-8.444778,-0.830497
-8.434778,-0.836026
-8.424778,-0.841471
-8.414778,-0.846832
-8.404778,-0.852108
-8.394778,-0.857299
-8.384778,-0.862404
-8.374778,-0.867423
-8.364778,-0.872355
-8.354778,-0.877201
-8.344778,-0.881958
-8.334778,-0.886627
-8.324778,-0.891207
-8.314778,-0.895699
-8.304778,-0.900100
-8.294778,-0.904412
-8.284778,-0.908633
-8.274778,-0.912764
-8.264778,-0.916803
-8.254778,-0.920751
-8.244778,-0.924606
-8.234778,-0.928369
-8.224778,-0.932039
-8.214778,-0.935616
-8.204778,-0.939099
-8.194778,-0.942489
-8.184778,-0.945784
-8.174778,-0.948985
-8.164778,-0.952090
-8.154778,-0.955101
-8.144778,-0.958016
-8.134778,-0.960835
-8.124778,-0.963558
-8.114778,-0.966185
-8.104778,-0.968715
-8.094778,-0.971148
-8.084778,-0.973485
-8.074778,-0.975723
-8.064778,-0.977865
-8.054778,-0.979908
-8.044778,-0.981854
-8.034778,-0.983701
-8.024778,-0.985450
-8.014778,-0.987100
-8.004778,-0.988652
-7.994778,-0.990105
-7.984778,-0.991458
-7.974778,-0.992713
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
        %width=0.4\textwidth,
        %height=0.4\textwidth,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={$Time[s]$},
        xlabel near ticks,
        ylabel={$Amplitude$},
        ylabel near ticks,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        name=MainPlot]
         \addplot[line width=2pt,solid] 
           table [x index=0, y index=1, col     
sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \node[pin={[pin edge={transparent}]100:{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
            \begin{axis}[
                y tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        fixed zerofill,
                        precision=2,
                    /tikz/.cd
                },
                x tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        fixed zerofill,
                        precision=2,
                    /tikz/.cd
                },
                tiny,
                yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize},
                xticklabel style = {font=\normalsize},
                xticklabel pos=upper,
                xmin=-6,
                xtick distance=1,
                xmax=-4,
                %xlabel={\normalsize $Time[s]$},
                xlabel near ticks,
                yticklabel pos=right,
                ymin=0.8,
                ytick distance=0.05,
                ymax=1,
                %ylabel={\normalsize $Amplitude$},
                ylabel near ticks,
                enlargelimits,
                axis background/.style={fill=white!10},
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ymajorgrids=true]
            \addplot [line width=2pt,solid] 
           table [x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }}]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your snippet makes use of a csv file, which you do not provide. Could you please either provide the package or, even better, rewrite your code in such a way that no file is needed? BTW, it is not recommended to nest tikzpicture environments.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to putting a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture is to use a savebox.  Vertical alignment is easy using the baseline, but there is no mechanism for horizontal alignment.  So instead I calculated the offset from the center to the upper right corner of the grid.  Note that these offsets needed to be scaled by the same factor as the tikzpicture.

Note, the data only went to -7 so most of the plot is missing.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
-9.424778,-0.000000
-9.414778,-0.010000
-9.404778,-0.019999
-9.394778,-0.029996
-9.384778,-0.039989
-9.374778,-0.049979
-9.364778,-0.059964
-9.354778,-0.069943
-9.344778,-0.079915
-9.334778,-0.089879
-9.324778,-0.099833
-9.314778,-0.109778
-9.304778,-0.119712
-9.294778,-0.129634
-9.284778,-0.139543
-9.274778,-0.149438
-9.264778,-0.159318
-9.254778,-0.169182
-9.244778,-0.179030
-9.234778,-0.188859
-9.224778,-0.198669
-9.214778,-0.208460
-9.204778,-0.218230
-9.194778,-0.227978
-9.184778,-0.237703
-9.174778,-0.247404
-9.164778,-0.257081
-9.154778,-0.266731
-9.144778,-0.276356
-9.134778,-0.285952
-9.124778,-0.295520
-9.114778,-0.305059
-9.104778,-0.314567
-9.094778,-0.324043
-9.084778,-0.333487
-9.074778,-0.342898
-9.064778,-0.352274
-9.054778,-0.361615
-9.044778,-0.370920
-9.034778,-0.380188
-9.024778,-0.389418
-9.014778,-0.398609
-9.004778,-0.407760
-8.994778,-0.416871
-8.984778,-0.425939
-8.974778,-0.434966
-8.964778,-0.443948
-8.954778,-0.452886
-8.944778,-0.461779
-8.934778,-0.470626
-8.924778,-0.479426
-8.914778,-0.488177
-8.904778,-0.496880
-8.894778,-0.505533
-8.884778,-0.514136
-8.874778,-0.522687
-8.864778,-0.531186
-8.854778,-0.539632
-8.844778,-0.548024
-8.834778,-0.556361
-8.824778,-0.564642
-8.814778,-0.572867
-8.804778,-0.581035
-8.794778,-0.589145
-8.784778,-0.597195
-8.774778,-0.605186
-8.764778,-0.613117
-8.754778,-0.620986
-8.744778,-0.628793
-8.734778,-0.636537
-8.724778,-0.644218
-8.714778,-0.651834
-8.704778,-0.659385
-8.694778,-0.666870
-8.684778,-0.674288
-8.674778,-0.681639
-8.664778,-0.688921
-8.654778,-0.696135
-8.644778,-0.703279
-8.634778,-0.710353
-8.624778,-0.717356
-8.614778,-0.724287
-8.604778,-0.731146
-8.594778,-0.737931
-8.584778,-0.744643
-8.574778,-0.751280
-8.564778,-0.757843
-8.554778,-0.764329
-8.544778,-0.770739
-8.534778,-0.777072
-8.524778,-0.783327
-8.514778,-0.789504
-8.504778,-0.795602
-8.494778,-0.801620
-8.484778,-0.807558
-8.474778,-0.813416
-8.464778,-0.819192
-8.454778,-0.824886
-8.444778,-0.830497
-8.434778,-0.836026
-8.424778,-0.841471
-8.414778,-0.846832
-8.404778,-0.852108
-8.394778,-0.857299
-8.384778,-0.862404
-8.374778,-0.867423
-8.364778,-0.872355
-8.354778,-0.877201
-8.344778,-0.881958
-8.334778,-0.886627
-8.324778,-0.891207
-8.314778,-0.895699
-8.304778,-0.900100
-8.294778,-0.904412
-8.284778,-0.908633
-8.274778,-0.912764
-8.264778,-0.916803
-8.254778,-0.920751
-8.244778,-0.924606
-8.234778,-0.928369
-8.224778,-0.932039
-8.214778,-0.935616
-8.204778,-0.939099
-8.194778,-0.942489
-8.184778,-0.945784
-8.174778,-0.948985
-8.164778,-0.952090
-8.154778,-0.955101
-8.144778,-0.958016
-8.134778,-0.960835
-8.124778,-0.963558
-8.114778,-0.966185
-8.104778,-0.968715
-8.094778,-0.971148
-8.084778,-0.973485
-8.074778,-0.975723
-8.064778,-0.977865
-8.054778,-0.979908
-8.044778,-0.981854
-8.034778,-0.983701
-8.024778,-0.985450
-8.014778,-0.987100
-8.004778,-0.988652
-7.994778,-0.990105
-7.984778,-0.991458
-7.974778,-0.992713
\end{filecontents*}

\newlength{\xshift}% reserve global names
\newlength{\yshift}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\begin{figure}
\sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
            \begin{axis}[name=grid,
                y tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        fixed zerofill,
                        precision=2,
                    /tikz/.cd
                },
                x tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                        fixed,
                        fixed zerofill,
                        precision=2,
                    /tikz/.cd
                },
                tiny,
                yticklabel style = {font=\normalsize},
                xticklabel style = {font=\normalsize},
                xticklabel pos=upper,
                xmin=-6,
                xtick distance=1,
                xmax=-4,
                %xlabel={\normalsize $Time[s]$},
                xlabel near ticks,
                yticklabel pos=right,
                ymin=0.8,
                ytick distance=0.05,
                ymax=1,
                %ylabel={\normalsize $Amplitude$},
                ylabel near ticks,
                enlargelimits,
                axis background/.style={fill=white!10},
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ymajorgrids=true]
            \addplot [line width=2pt,solid] 
           table [x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
        \pgfextractx{\xshift}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{grid}{north east}}%
          {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{center}}}
        \pgfextracty{\yshift}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{grid}{north east}}%
          {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{center}}}
        \global\xshift=\xshift
        \global\yshift=\yshift
\end{tikzpicture}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
        %width=0.4\textwidth,
        %height=0.4\textwidth,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={$Time[s]$},
        xlabel near ticks,
        ylabel={$Amplitude$},
        ylabel near ticks,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        name=MainPlot]
         \addplot[line width=2pt,solid] 
           table [x index=0, y index=1, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \node[xshift=0.6\xshift,yshift=0.6\yshift] at(MainPlot.north east) {\usebox0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for example. However, I have one error during compilation: "! Package pgf Error: No shape named grid is known." why ?

Comment: Should have used a full replacement in my previous edit.  Sorry about that.